# How to auto-sync a quote and an opportunity in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, opportunity, quote, sync

For Classic this is an old question, which can be solved via an Apex trigger. This is the code that I am using now:

```
trigger QuoteAutoSync on Quote (after insert) {
    Map<Id, Id> quoteMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Quote currentQuote : Trigger.New) {
        quoteMap.put(currentQuote.Id, currentQuote.OpportunityId);
    }
    Quotes.syncQuote(quoteMap);
}
```

What I observe in Classic: the quote gets created, with line items. It has not been synchronized yet (the button is still called Start Sync). But when I refresh the screen, the quote has been synced.

It turns out that this is not working in Lightning. I end up with a synced quote that has zero line items, and because of the synchronization, the products have been removed from the opportunity. It almost seems like the quote is created, and it is synced before any products have been copied from the opportunity to the quote.

In theory a solution would be to use the Process Builder, but I can't get this to work, even in Classic: I end up with an empty quote and opportunity. For one thing, I am looking for an opportunity field called SyncedQuoteId, but I cannot find that in the Process Builder. I did find an opportunity field called QuoteId, but updating that doesn't work for me.

I know there is a known issue for Salesforce that you can't create a filled Quote from an Opportunity using a Quick action, but I am using the default 'New Quote' button and without an active trigger or process, I get a filled quote from an opportunity. It's just not synced, as I'd like to.